# Wireless not working on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-12.04

I just install ubuntu 12.04 but wirelless not works(windows 7 wirelless works).

I open my windows 7 and see under Network Adapters:

```
   Edimax 802.11n Wireless Adapter

   Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
```

Which drivers i should download to install them on ubuntu 12.04 to make wireless work?
And how i install this drivers on ubuntu after i copy them to usb.

(I can have only wireless connection not wire - soo i nhave to dowload the drivers with windows then copy them to ubuntu)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is that a PCI or a USB adapter? What is the output of

```
lspci | grep -i wireless
```

or

```
lsusb | grep -i wireless
```

respectively? Do you have NetworkManager installed?

```
dpkg -l | grep network-manager
```